# Can we pass additional parameters along with render method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Controller method:

```
def add
@project = Project.find(1)
render xml: @project  #wish to pass one more variable like this here
end
```

ajax call :

```
endpoint = ROOT_PATH + '/projects/add/'+data_type;
    $.ajax({
            url : endpoint,
            type : "get",
            dataType : "xml",
            success : function(xml) {

                            id = $(xml).find('id').text();
                title = $(xml).find('title').text();

                   // wish to display the sent additional parameter here.
    }
    });
```

I am able to get project instance parameters 'id' and 'title' in the ajax call.But I wish to send one more parameter along with the @project and wish to use the value of this parameter inside the ajax call. Could some one help me out pls. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways could be:

```
 render xml: @patient.as_json.merge({:YOUR_KEY => YOUR_VALUE})
```

if you want to send the requested params or nil @patient then:

```
requested_params = params.except(:controller, :action)
render xml: @patient.present? ? @patient.as_json.merge(requested_params) : requested_params`
```

Comment: ...but if @patient=1 ...this methode fails with the error undefinedmethodError (undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum) ...what can be done in this case ?

Comment: I considered `@patient` is as an activerecord object. if you expect `@patient` as something different then clarify it :)

Comment: if requestOK = '3'
  project = 1         
end ... i am jus passing a random number to project .... because render requires something .... otherwise the ajax call would not be successful if project is nil.

Comment: .... so if the atproject=1 .....what happens ? will it not merge the additional parameter ? I want to merge it even if project value is 1 ..pls let me know

Comment: `@project` value should not be 1, if you really need that the use project_id instead and to return `requested_params.merge(project_id: PROJECT_ID)`